# Javascript: Extract data from option list

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

I am trying to get data from a php sub-page.
Using javascript, I have tried to use :

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('option');
console.log("length : "+items.length);
```

```html
  <option value="75">item-127 ( 120127 )</option>
  <option value="74">item-163 ( 0 )</option>
  <option value="94">item-139 ( 0 )</option>
  <option value="89">item-135 ( 0 )</option>
  <option value="369">Item-AC95 ( AC95 )</option>
  <option value="63">item-159 ( 120159 )</option>
```

But it does not return the expected length:
length : 0
How could I do it?

The final expectation is having a table with values and items

thanks

Comment: The source I have to extract has only <option>. It is resulting from a php sub-page. And I can not change it.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget that `<options>` tend to appear only within a `<select>` tag.

Your code works fine. checkout the snippet below.

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('option');

console.log('There are ' + items.length + ' options');

items.forEach(function(option,i){
   console.log('option #' + i + '  has value ' + option.value + ' and html:' + option.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
<option value="75">item-127 ( 120127 )</option>
<option value="74">item-163 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="94">item-139 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="89">item-135 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="369">Item-AC95 ( AC95 )</option>
<option value="63">item-159 ( 120159 )</option>
</select>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The real source that I have to extract does not contain <html> nor <body>. And I can not change it, and add <select>, as this is not my website. It is the output of a php sub-page.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `<option>` tag must be enclosed by `<select>`.Here is the code to retrieve the value from the option

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('option');
for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
       item = items[i];
       if (item.value != "") {
       
           alert(item.value);
       }
     }
```

```html
<option value="75">item-127 ( 120127 )</option>
<option value="74">item-163 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="94">item-139 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="89">item-135 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="369">Item-AC95 ( AC95 )</option>
<option value="63">item-159 ( 120159 )</option>
```

Comment: using forEach would be a little cleaner. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you aware but assigning a variable doesn't output things, you could use `console.log()` by example.

```js
const values = document.querySelectorAll('option');

console.log(values);
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<option value="75">item-127 ( 120127 )</option>
<option value="74">item-163 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="94">item-139 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="89">item-135 ( 0 )</option>
<option value="369">Item-AC95 ( AC95 )</option>
<option value="63">item-159 ( 120159 )</option>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code was only a small part. Of course, I use console.log to display values. But my variable is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should wrap your `<option>` elements in a `<select>`.

Secondly the code you provided gives you a HTMLNodeList object with `<option>` as elements of it. Their values are under `items[0].value` and the item itself is under `items[0].innerHTML` or `items[0].textContent`

```js
let options = items.map((option) => {
  console.log(`Item: ${option.textContent}, value: ${option.value}`); 
})
```